# Creating nested json object based on given condition

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a flat list (array of objects), like next one:

```
var myList = [
  {id:1, name:"ABC", type:"level_1"},
  {id:2, name:"XYZ", type:"level_1"},
  {id:1, name:"ABC_level 2", type:"level_2", level_one_id:1},
  {id:2, name:"XYZ_level 2", type:"level_2", level_one_id:2},
  {id:1, name:"ABC_level 3", type:"level_3", level_two_id:1},
  {id:2, name:"XYZ_level 3", type:"level_3", level_two_id:2},
];
```

Then, I have to group them in such a way that I can create a hierarchy of levels (which I tried to do in the below lines of code):

```js
var myList = [
  {id:1, name:"ABC", type:"level_1"},
  {id:2, name:"XYZ", type:"level_1"},
  {id:1, name:"ABC_level 2", type:"level_2", level_one_id:1},
  {id:2, name:"XYZ_level 2", type:"level_2", level_one_id:2},
  {id:1, name:"ABC_level 3", type:"level_3", level_two_id:1},
  {id:2, name:"XYZ_level 3", type:"level_3", level_two_id:2},
];

var myNestedList = {
    levels: []
};
    
//-----------pushing level1----------

myList.forEach((res => {
    if (res.type == "level_1") {
        myNestedList.levels.push(res);
    }
}));

//-----------pushing level 2---------

myNestedList.levels.forEach((res) => {
    myList.forEach((val) => {
        if (val.type == "level_2" && val.level_one_id == res.id) {
            res["level_2"] = [] || res["level_2"];
            res["level_2"].push(val);
        }
    })
})
    
//-----------pushing level 3---------
    
myNestedList.levels.forEach((res) => {
    res["level_2"].forEach((val) => {
        myList.forEach((lastlevel) => {
            if (lastlevel.type == "level_3" && lastlevel.level_two_id == val.id) {
                val["level_3"] = [] || val["level_3"];
                val["level_3"].push(lastlevel);
            }
        })
    })
})

console.log(myNestedList);
```

Although I'm able to achieve the result, I'm sure this code can be more precise and meaningful. Can we make use of lodash here and get this code shorter?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: do you have a wanted result? why the changing name like `level_one_id` instead of a parent property?

Comment: @NinaScholz `level_one_id`: this will indicate me of the parent id and then I'll be able to group them accordingly.

Comment: I think the point is that if they had a consistent `parent` field, it would make life quite a bit easier to work with.  But the repeated ids across levels would likely still cause problems.

Comment: @ScottSauyet This is the data I have it for now. But even in the case of consistent `parent` field, I have to loop them anyway with above code.

Comment: In other words, your tree structure is not at all obvious from the data supplied.  What tells us that `{id:2, name:"XYZ_level 2", type:"level_2", level_one_id:2}` belongs under `{id:2, name:"XYZ", type:"level_1"}` and not under `{id:1, name:"ABC", type:"level_1"}`?  Just the coincidence of the names XYZ vs ABC?

Comment: If the structure was somehow inherent in the data, you could probably have some recursive solution that didn't need such level-specific loops.  But as it is, I can't even see how you can really describe a tree.

Comment: Is it true that every node but the root can only have one child?  That this is not really a tree but an array of ordered lists?  If not, I can't see how you can determine nesting structure from the data.  If there are two things at level 2 under id 1, what tells me under which one of them to put an id 1, level 3 item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a virtual unique `id` for the object and for referencing the parents and collect the items in a tree.

This approach works with unsorted data as well.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, name: "ABC", type: "level_1" }, { id: 2, name: "XYZ", type: "level_1" }, { id: 1, name: "ABC_level 2", type: "level_2", level_one_id: 1 }, { id: 2, name: "XYZ_level 2", type: "level_2", level_one_id: 2 }, { id: 1, name: "ABC_level 3", type: "level_3", level_two_id: 1 }, { id: 2, name: "XYZ_level 3", type: "level_3", level_two_id: 2 }],
    tree = function (data) {
        var t = {};
        data.forEach(o => {
            var level = o.type.match(/\d+$/)[0],
                parent = o[Object.keys(o).filter(k => k.startsWith('level_'))[0]] || 0,
                parentId = `${level - 1}.${parent}`,
                id = `${level}.${o.id}`,
                children = `level_${level}`;

            Object.assign(t[id] = t[id] || {}, o);
            t[parentId] = t[parentId] || {};
            t[parentId][children] = t[parentId][children] || [];
            t[parentId][children].push(t[id]);
        });
        return t['0.0'].level_1;
    }(data);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Note that the original output (if that's really what's wanted) does not have `children` nodes.  Instead it has nodes like `level_2` and `level_3`.

Comment: the problem is, i see no wanted result. but it's no problem to address a dynamic children array.

Comment: I just ran the code supplied.  I'm assuming that the output is what's desired, and the goal is cleaner code.  But I could be way off.

Comment: I'm still pretty confused by the structure, myself!

Answer (score 2):

I can't make any sense of this data representing a real tree.  But I can see it turning into something like a list of lists, one for each base id, something like this:

```js
[
  [
    {id: 1, name: "ABC", type: "level_1"},
    {id: 1, name: "ABC_level 2", type: "level_2", level_one_id: 1},
    {id: 1, name: "ABC_level 3", type: "level_3", level_two_id: 1}
  ],
  [
    {id: 2, name: "XYZ", type: "level_1"},
    {id: 2, name: "XYZ_level 2", type: "level_2", level_one_id: 2},
    {id: 2, name: "XYZ_level 3", type: "level_3", level_two_id: 2}
  ]
]
```

If that format is useful, then this code could help you get there:

```js
// utility function
const group = (fn) => (xs) =>
  Object .values (xs .reduce ((a, x) => ({...a, [fn (x)]: (a [fn (x)] || []) .concat (x)}), {}))

// helper function
const numericSuffix = str => Number (str .type .match (/(\d+)$/) [1])

// main function -- I don't have a sense of what a good name for this would be
const foo = (xs) => 
  group (o => o.id) (xs)
    .map (x => x .sort ((a, b) => numericSuffix(a) - numericSuffix(b)))

// data
const myList = [{id: 1, name: "ABC", type: "level_1"}, {id: 2, name: "XYZ", type: "level_1"}, {id: 1, name: "ABC_level 2", type: "level_2", level_one_id: 1}, {id: 2, name: "XYZ_level 2", type: "level_2", level_one_id: 2}, {id: 1, name: "ABC_level 3", type: "level_3", level_two_id: 1}, {id: 2, name: "XYZ_level 3", type: "level_3", level_two_id: 2}]

// demo
console .log (foo (myList))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We use a custom `group` function as well as one that extracts the numeric end of a string (to be used in sorting so that `level_10` comes after `level_9` and not before `level_2`)  `group` could be replaced by Underscore, lodash or Ramda `groupBy` functions, but you'd probably then have to call `Object.values()` on the results.

The main function groups the data on their ids, then sorts the group by that numeric suffix.

Note that this technique only makes sense if there is only one element for a given id at any particular level.  If there could be more, and you really need a tree, I don't see how your input structure could determine future nesting.